# put operation on Angular5

Tags: html, angular, typescript, frontend

I have a table in DB called `settings`.
On the backend I have 2 endpoints: get settings and put settings.

Now I try to create the window to edit this table in Angular.

I created Angular Service to get values:

```
findUserSettings(): Observable<UserSettings> {
const userServiceUrl = environment.backendUrl + '/users/settings';
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json'
  })
};
return this.http.get<UserSettings>(userServiceUrl, httpOptions);
}
editUserSettings(userSettings: UserSettings): Observable<Object> {
const userUrl = environment.backendUrl + '/users/settings';
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json'
  })
}
return this.http.put(userUrl, userSettings, httpOptions)
```

}

now in my component I try to get data from those requests by methods like this:

```
findUserSettings(){
this.userService.findUserSettings().subscribe(
  success => {
    this.formData = success;
  },
  error => {
    console.error(error);
  },
  () => {
  }
);
}

getFirstDayOfWeek(){
this.userService.findUserSettings().subscribe(
  success => {
    this.formData.firstDayOfWeek = success.firstDayOfWeek;
  },
  error => {
    console.error(error);
  },
  () => {
  }
);
}

saveUserSettings(){
this.userService.editUserSettings(this.formData).subscribe(
  data => {
    this.formDataSaved.emit(true);
  }
);
}
```

I created HTML template with the button to add, but I dont know how to pass the body of that method.

```
    <select class="form-control" id="select">
        <option value="1">My enum here.</option>
      </select>
    <button class="btn btn-default" (click)="saveUserSettings()">Save</button>
```

This is the moment where I miss the point and don't know how to move forward.
I need to pass the body to the method, but hardly don't know how.

The body it requires looks like this:

```
import { User } from "./user";

export class UserSettings {
  id: number;
  User: User;
  firstDayOfWeek: Day;
}
```

The day is an enum like below:

```
enum Day {
    SUNDAY = 'su',
    MONDAY = 'mo',
    TUESDAY = 'tu',
    WEDNESDAY = 'we',
    THURSDAY = 'th',
    FRIDAY = 'fr', 
    SATURDAY = 'sa', 
}
```

I would like to let the user chose the `firstDayOfWeek` only here, and then press button to make this put operation.
Any idea what should I do now?

How to pass body to the method from html, and how to add String enum to the select to be able to change this db record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

In your **TS-File**

Import your enum. Create a local copy of your enum. Extract the keys.

```
import { Day } from '../enums/enums';

keys: any[];
days = Day; // local instance of your enum

constructor() {
   this.keys = Object.keys(this.days);
}
```

In your **HTML-template**

Bind your `select-box` to the `firstDayOfWeek` field in `userSettings`. Build up the option list of days.

```
<select class="form-control" id="select" [(ngModel)]="userSettings.firstDayOfWeek">
   <option *ngFor="let key of keys" [value]="days[key]">{{key}}</option>
</select>
```

If you now click an option the `firstDayOfWeek` field in `userSettings` gets directly updated with the corresponding enum-value e.g. `mo`, `su` and so on. You can then directly persist it.

Don't forget that you need access to your enum Day. The easiest way is to put it at the end of your TS-file.

Comment: earlier I had ERROR in src/app/holiday/component/user-settings-form/user-settings-form.component.ts(22,46): error TS2693: 'string' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here. which I changed for String from capital letter.

Comment: no, still have an error from bastein (first comment) pastebin.com/raw/JzSGKEg4

Comment: Okay, then I have to rethink it. Sorry. The example derives originally from a solution with enums having a Number as key. I'll get back to you as soon as possible. Or do you see any chance changing firstDayOfWeek from your 2 letter string representation to a Number?

Comment: Okay, I'll get back to you soon. Approx. within the next 4-5 hours. appointments...

Comment: Thanks mate, will be waiting :)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your patience. So here is the final solution. I edited my answer. It runs on my machine like a charm. -- If this answer helped you, please don't forget to mark it as solution.

Comment: well, don't know why, but I get an error at line where I declare my local instance of my enum (days = Day;) - Day undefined. :(

Comment: Do you have your enum Day in your ts-file?

Comment: Okay, that is the problem. You have to import it. I updated my code. But this is just an assumption. You have to fit this import to your actual directory-structure.